# Unable to bind dropdown list using knockout

Tags: html, knockout.js

I need to bind the html 'select' (dropdown) below. When I tried to bind the below code outside the `<tbody data-bind="foreach: obtainedMarksArr">` code then It works well. But you can see in HTML code below that when we placed it inside the `<tbody data-bind="foreach: obtainedMarksArr">` code then it gives following error:

Error: "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'obtainedMarksArr' is undefined".

------------------------ Page-Code -----------------------------

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/myTestStyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var uri = 'api/students';
        function AppViewModel(item) {

            var self = this;
            self.obtainedMarksArr = ko.observableArray();

            for (var i = 0; i < item.ObtainedMarksList.length; i++) {

                self.obtainedMarksArr.push({ course: item.ObtainedMarksList[i].courseName, totalmarks: item.ObtainedMarksList[i].TotalMarks, obtainedMarks: item.ObtainedMarksList[i].ObtainedMarks });
            }
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON(uri)
              .done(function (data) {
                  //Apply binding here:
                  ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(data));

              });
        });
    </script>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="div1">


    <table class="marginTable2">
        <thead>
            <tr class="ThColor">
                <th class="textCenter ThColor topThColor" colspan="4">Obained Marks List</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="ThColor">
                <th class="textLeft ThColor">Course</th>
                <th class="textLeft ThColor">Total Marks</th>
                <th class="textLeft ThColor">Obtained Marks</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: obtainedMarksArr">
            <tr class="TrColor">
                <td class="textLeft"><select data-bind="options: obtainedMarksArr, optionsText: 'course'"></select></td>
                <td class="textLeft"><input data-bind="value: totalmarks" /></td>
                <td class="textLeft"><input data-bind="value: obtainedMarks" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Am I missing something. I really appreciate your answer.

Thanks.

Comment: To which html element do you apply/bind you viewModel? We need a bit more code in order to be able to answer the question.

Comment: @Major, <select data-bind="options: obtainedMarksArr, optionsText: 'course'"></select>    It's html select.

Comment: still missing how you apply your binding and to what, i.e. `ko.applyBinding(model, element)`

Comment: @MajorByte, plz see know, i have added the whole code.

Comment: @MajorByte, it's not working, i have not used 'obtainedMarks' in my code, so how can i use it. please see the screen shot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `foreach: obtainedMarskArr` you context is changed to just that. 
The `<select data-bind="options: obtainedMarksArr`is the problem here, should be `<select data-bind="options: obtainedMarks` because you are working with these objects now, for each `tr` you create

```
{ 
  course: item.ObtainedMarksList[i].courseName, 
  totalmarks: item.ObtainedMarksList[i].TotalMarks, 
  obtainedMarks: item.ObtainedMarksList[i].ObtainedMarks 
}
```

Or, if you need the dropdown to be obtainedMarskArr, you could do: `<select data-bind="options: $root.obtainedMarksArr`

Comment: it's not working, i have not used 'obtainedMarks' in my code, so how can we use it.

Comment: But you don't seem to understand that inside the foreach the scope has changed to the object that you push on the array. The objects in your array don't have a obtainedMarksArr. And first I thought that was just a typo. But you need to get `obtainedMarksArr` from you viewmodel with either `$root.obtainedMarksArr` or `$parent.obtainedMarksArr` as I added in the answer.

Comment: I know that it's scope has changed here.

Comment: so, does `<td class="textLeft"><select data-bind="options: $root.obtainedMarksArr, optionsText: 'course'"></select></td>` work?

Comment: i have another question, when i tried to add a new row then each time on button click, an extra blank option inserted in the ddl. This is the code,                               self.addMarksItem = function () {
                self.obtainedMarksArr.push({ course: '', totalmarks: '', obtainedMarks: '' });
            };

Comment: Please write it as a new question, comments aren't for questions. That said, you use the same observable array for the dropdown as for your foreach, so that isn't odd at all....